# Array_agg not allowed within UNNEST in bigquery | Google Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, unnest, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

I am trying converting Hive QL to Bigquery SQL

**Hive Query**

```
create table d_bu as
select
itapp_id,
it_acronym,
concat_ws(',',sort_array(split(concat_ws(":", collect_set(it_unit)),':'))) as merged_BU,
case when lower(domain) in ('csms','ucmdb') then 'yes' when lower(line_of_business) in ('psbms','retail','hosted') then 'yes' else 'no' end as heritage
from db.table_bkp
group by itapp_id,
it_acronym,
domain,
line_of_business;
```

**BigQuery converted**

```
CREATE TABLE db.d_bu
 AS
  SELECT
    table_bkp.itapp_id,
    table_bkp.it_acronym,
    array_to_string(ARRAY (
     SELECT
       v
      FROM
       UNNEST(split(array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT table_bkp.it_unit), ':'), ':')) AS v
     ORDER BY
      v
    ), ',') AS merged_bu,
    CASE
     WHEN lower(table_bkp.domain) IN(
      'csms', 'ucmdb'
     ) THEN 'yes'
     WHEN lower(table_bkp.line_of_business) IN(
      'psbms', 'retail', 'hosted'
     ) THEN 'yes'
     ELSE 'no'
    END AS heritage
   FROM
    db.table_bkp
   GROUP BY 1, 2, table_bkp.domain, table_bkp.line_of_business
;
```

I tried multiple ways but, I am getting this error running the BQ SQL stating, `Aggregate function array_agg is not allowed under Unnest`

Can someone please look into it if the conversion is correct or not?

Comment: You can perform the array_agg in a with close and then use it as unnest.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you so much. I didn't think of that. It was really easy, just created a temporary table instead of using CTE as suggested and it really worked.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregation for `merged_bu` column seems too complicated.
If you want a *sorted, de-duplicated CSV* string, you can simple write it like below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH table_bkp AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('badfbkzjdidwwkdefjdfka', '')) it_unit
)
-- aggregation query starts here
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT it_unit ORDER BY it_unit) AS merged_bu
  FROM table_bkp;

-- query result
+-----------------------+
|       merged_bu       |
+-----------------------+
| "a,b,d,e,f,i,j,k,w,z" |
+-----------------------+
```